ESP32 Schematic and PCB Design using Altium
Please review my schematic and PCB design. Purpose of the board is to reduce the current consumption of ESP32. I have used RT9080 voltage regulator. Board is powered either by USB or by battery (4.2V). P-MOSFET is used to switch between USB and Battery ( By default battery will power the board but when both battery and usb are present, board will be switched to USB by MOSFET). DS18B20 temp. sensor and ADXL345 sensor are used to measure temp. and accelaration respectively. CP2102 USB to UART bridge is used. PCB is designed using Altium. Board is two layer and most of the routing is done on top layer and ground on both layers. I shall be grateful for the feedback.



The RT9080 is a Linear Regulator which could reduce battery life compared to using a switching regulator. How much current are the components expected to draw and how long do you need the circuit to run off the battery?

The first thing I noticed was USB D+/D- lines: re-route them for 90 Ohms differential impedance (You will quite possibly end up with disturbingly thick traces since the board has only 2 layers.).

@RohatKılıç is not that necessary for high speed signals? As i read that for this we can route like this. In this forum someone answered this question that it will work fine.

@ChesterGillon in the next step i can use switching regulator.

@Umar is not that necessary for high speed signals? isn't the USB high-speed? USB 2.0 is usually forgiving but still, better to do the "right" way.

Curious why the ground cutout under U2? Also, if this board is going to be reflow soldered you could turn off thermal reliefs for SMD pads.

As for the temperature: this will measure the temperature of the PCB, which will be warm. If you want the air temperature, use a sensor on a lead, or have a look at the techniques here: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa967a/snoa967a.pdf (you can skip to section 2 on page 11)

@DamienD thanks for the comment. I will use sensor on a lead. I didn't consider before. Thanks


The Keep-out(copper-free) zone around the ESP32 antenna need to be at least 15mm based on ESP32 hardware design guide, which means that you need to expand keep-out zone to the width of the PCB, and align your ESP32 to the edge cut instead of leaving a close copper loop around the antenna as you had it now.

Unless the ESP32 in deep sleep mode most of time (since it is battery-powered), otherwise I would suggest to move the temperature sensor away from ESP32 as ESP32 running at 240MHz could reached to 60-70c internally quickly, and even at 80MHz at around 40-50c, and it will affect the temperature by 1 to 3 degrees.

The USB shield is typically ground by the host side via cable, so it shouldn't connect to the GND on the ESP32 board side.


There are a few minor things that could be done better but those are the 3 major ones that I saw so far.
